Improve g++ compiler flags for debug and release
I am making a game in c++ with sdl2, and I am currently compiling the program with g++ using the following flags:
DEBUG_FLAGS = -g -Og -DDEBUG
RELEASE_FLAGS = -O3 -DNDEBUG -mwindows -s

I want the debug build to have as many debug symbols as possible, and I want the release build to sacrifice file size for the most compatibility and performance. I also don't want my class and function names in the release build. Also, I do intend for the game to run on platforms other than windows.
So far, these flags have worked, but I am curious about adding things like -flto, -Wall, -Wextra, -pedantic, and -std=c++17. Also, I am not sure if -DNDEBUG is necessary with -O3, and if -DDEBUG is necessary with -Og.

-Wall, -Wextra + -Werror must have, btw they have nothing to do with optimizations and debug symbols.

I am not sure if -DNDEBUG is necessary with -O3 -- Well, that is easily tested here with a simple one line program that calls assert.  The assert is a no-op if -DNDEBUG is defined, so yes, you have to explicitly have it in your command-line arguments.

@PaulMcKenzie Thanks! Also, I tried -Og with -DDEBUG and without, and it returned the same thing both times. Does this mean -DDEBUG isn't required with -Og?

@273K Thanks! However, this makes the compiler not like my main function: "int main(int argc, char* args[])" (it says that argc and args are unused parameters). I was told to initialize my main function like this when using SDL2, but should I not?

main may have either the signature int main() or int main(int, char**) (or possibly other, implementation defined options).  If you don't need argc and argv for accepting command line options then you can use the no-args signature.

@MilesBudnek I see! I though SDL2 needed argc and args to work. Thanks!

You should be able to use int main(int, char**) and not name the arguments to avoid the warnings/errors and still match the SDL_main signature it is looking for.

@RetiredNinja That works perfectly with no errors! Thanks!

I'm not sure if -DDEBUG does anything. I'd recommend adding -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG to debug builds to enable container bounds checking. Also -pedantic-errors (in both) is a good idea to ensure standard compliance. (-pedantc has the same effect, but gives warnings instead of errors, which doens't matter since you have -Werror).

@HolyBlackCat I decided to add -pedantic instead of -pedantic-errors since I am using -Werror, and I added -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG. Now the only flag left is -flto! Also, what is the difference between -pedantic and -Wpedantic?

I believe there's none, but you can check GCC manual.

@HolyBlackCat it looks like there isn't a difference. Looking at these docs, -Wpedantic has nothing after it, so I assume that means that it does the same thing as pedantic. I'll use Wpedantic so that it matches all of the other flags.

One more thing, you list all the flags in one place, while some of them are compiler flags, some are linker flags, and some apply to both.

@HolyBlackCat I know -mwindows and -s are linker flags and the rest are compiler flags, but which are both?

I suggest moving the information answering the question into the "answer" box. This will make it clear to future readers which question you are answering. I imagine the answer is going to be useful for quite a lot of people, so please make it easier for them to find the answer. Also, optionally, make it "community wiki" because several people contributed to it.

I'd pass -g and -O... to both, just in case. -flto definitely needs to be in both.

@HolyBlackCat I'll add -flto to both, but I'm not sure about adding -g to the release build.

I mean if you're adding it to compiler flags, also add it to linker flags. Not saying to add it in release build.

@HolyBlackCat Should I add -flto to both release and debug?

I decided to remove -flto from the debug flags in case it could interfere with debugging.

Only release, probably.

IIRC, -g3 enables the most expressive debug symbols for GCC.

@JesperJuhl Thanks! I didn't know that! I'll change the flags.

now me! Not mentioned that I have: -fnanalyzer -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fstack-protector-all -fstack-protector-strong -ggdb3 -grecord-gcc-switches -fcf-protection -D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpie -Wl,-pie -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,relro -fsanitize=address,undefined,pointer-compare,pointer-subtract. I do not know about windows. And consider using a build system, like CMake or Scons or Bazel, that can help with portability between compiler versions and platforms.

You may also find this useful: https://best.openssf.org/Compiler-Hardening-Guides/Compiler-Options-Hardening-Guide-for-C-and-C++

Does anyone know if -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 and -fstack-protector-strong overlap on what they do?

I have settled on the following flags:
COMMON_FLAGS = -std=c++17
WARNING_FLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wformat=2 -Wconversion -Wtrampolines -Wshadow -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Werror
DEBUG_FLAGS = -g3 -Og -D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS
RELEASE_FLAGS = -O3 -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mwindows -s -flto -fstack-protector-strong

I added -std=c++17 to the common flags to make sure the compiler uses c++ 17.
I added several warning flags to warn me in case I do something against the standard, and I added -Werror to turn all warnings into errors.
I also changed -g to -g3 in the debug flags, and changed -DDEBUG (which does nothing with -Og and -g) to -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG.
Finally, I added -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 to enable buffer overflow protection, -flto to enable link time optimizations, and -fstack-protector-strong to protect the stack.



Flag
Debug
Release
Justification




-std=c++17
x
x
compatibility


-Wall
x
x
best practice


-Wextra
x
x
best practice


-Wpedantic
x
x
compatibility


-Wformat=2
x
x
best practice


-Wconversion
x
x
best practice


-Wtrampolines
x
x
best practice


-Wshadow
x
x
best practice


-Wold-style-cast
x
x
best practice


-Woverloaded-virtual
x
x
best practice


-Werror
x
x
best practice


-g3
x

debugging


-Og
x

debugging


-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG
x

debugging


-O3

x
performance


-DNDEBUG

x
performance


-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2

x
protection


-mwindows

x
hide console


-s

x
file size


-flto

x
performance


-fstack-protector-strong

x
protection




Assuming you're using Make, it's worth defining COMMON_CFLAGS = -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror (etc.) that can be expanded in both your sets, rather than having two versions that need to be kept in sync with each other.
